# Rails 3 strip whitespace before_validation on all forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, whitespace, dry, helper

I'm relatively new to Rails and a bit surprised this isn't a configurable behavior...at least not one I've been able to find yet?!? I would have thought that 99% of forms would benefit from whitespace being trimmed from all `string` & `text` fields?!? Guess I'm wrong...

Regardless, I'm looking for a DRY way to strip all whitespace from form fields (of type :string & :text) in a Rails 3 app.

The Views have Helpers that are automatically referenced (included?) and available to each view...but Models don't seem to have such a thing?!? Or do they?

So currently I doing the following which *first* **requires** and *then* **includes** the whitespace_helper (aka WhitespaceHelper). but this still doesn't seem very DRY to me but it works...

ClassName.rb:

```
require 'whitespace_helper'

class ClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WhitespaceHelper
  before_validation :strip_blanks

  ...

  protected

   def strip_blanks
     self.attributeA.strip!
     self.attributeB.strip!
     ...
   end
```

lib/whitespace_helper.rb:

```
module WhitespaceHelper
  def strip_whitespace
    self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value| 
    self[key] = value.strip if value.respond_to?('strip')
  end
end
```

I guess I'm looking for a single (D.R.Y.) method (class?) to put somewhere (`lib/` ?) that would take a list of params (or attributes) and remove the whitespace (`.strip!`  ?) from each attribute w/out being named specifically.

Comment: You can put it in a helper and include it in your model

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a DRY way to use strip on all :params when creating a new model in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272028/is-there-a-dry-way-to-use-strip-on-all-params-when-creating-a-new-model-in-rails)

Comment: Thanks but this only seems to work if I first `require whitespace_helper` and then `include WhitespaceHelper` in the same file.  How is this DRY? Seems redundant...can someone explain?

Comment: The 'include' is for including a module into a class. You can have a module and a class in the same file. If you want the class to include that module, you still have to use the 'include' statement. The 'require' statement loads a ruby file. Loading a file doesn't include it in the class, which is why you need include as well.

Comment: Thanks! So, I guess this boils down to the essence of my question... If I want to access that simple 2 (4?, 6?) line helper `WhitespaceHelper` in ALL my models that use forms for input then I NEED To add both `require` and `include` to every `model.rb` file? Just doesn't seem very Ruby-esque or DRY to me?!?  I feel like I must be missing something?  How can the Views (and even Controllers) be so **helper** friendly yet the Models are not?

Comment: Note I haven't tried this and it might be a crazy idea, but you could create a class like this:
`
MyActiveRecordBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'whitespace_helper'  
  include WhitespaceHelper
end
`
... and then have your models inherit from that instead of AR::Base:

`
MyModel < MyActiveRecordBase
  # stuff
end
`

Answer (score 8):

Create a `before_validation` helper as seen [here](http://scottmoonen.com/2009/05/08/rails-pattern-trim-spaces-on-input/)

```
module Trimmer
  def trimmed_fields *field_list  
    before_validation do |model|
      field_list.each do |n|
        model[n] = model[n].strip if model[n].respond_to?('strip')
      end
    end
  end
end

require 'trimmer'
class ClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Trimmer
  trimmed_fields :attributeA, :attributeB
end
```

Comment: Why don't you just define the method on Trimmer and `extend Trimmer` in the class?

Comment: @Semyon just convention, that would work as well. This way you can include instance and class helpers in the same module. I've updated the example to use `ActiveSupport::Concern` which is much easier to read.

Comment: Meh, `ActiveSupport::Concern` is cool, but extend is simpler in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AutoStripAttributes gem for Rails](https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes). it'll help you to easily and cleanly accomplish the task.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Normal usage where " aaa   bbb\t " changes to "aaa bbb"
  auto_strip_attributes :nick, :comment

  # Squeezes spaces inside the string: "James   Bond  " => "James Bond"
  auto_strip_attributes :name, :squish => true

  # Won't set to null even if string is blank. "   " => ""
  auto_strip_attributes :email, :nullify => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Note I haven't tried this and it might be a crazy idea, but you could create a class like this:

```
MyActiveRecordBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'whitespace_helper'  
  include WhitespaceHelper
end
```

... and then have your models inherit from that instead of AR::Base:

```
MyModel < MyActiveRecordBase
  # stuff
end
```